# PHP Log in - multiple IF conditions not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

I have a system i have made for my work with multiple forms and admin consoles. However i currently have a different log in MYSQL DB for each one. Each one containing users for that section of the "system".

So i am trying to add everything in to one DB and pass a session variable. The variable is 'true'. my code on the page looks like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 && $_SESSION['breach'] != 'true') {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in as an admin!";
    echo 'true';
    header("location: /admin.php");
} else {
    // Makes it easier to read
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo 'false';
}
```

I added the echo true/false to see if it works. If I pass the $_SESSION['breach'] variable in the html it does display the word true. So i know the variable is working and passing through from the log in page to this one. Below is the snippet of the variables in the html being displayed.

```
 <p style="float:right;">You are logged in as: <?= $_SESSION['username'] ?></p><br>
 <p style="float:right;">Your profile: <?= $_SESSION['breach'] ?></p>
```

My DB for users literally is just

```
id | username | password | breach
1     test       bcrypt     true
2     test1      bcrypt
```

So i want test 1 to access the page and test 1 to be redirected to /admin.php

Comment: `echo true` outputs 1. You should try some different word.

Comment: I think session breach might be a boolean, try: $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 && !$_SESSION['breach']

Comment: Use var_dump() to check the type of any var

Comment: try o change `$_SESSION['breach'] != true`

Comment: I have changed the echo 'test'; to echo 'test'; and i still get false from echo 'false' as the answer even when the variables are bringing back nothing for breach. But when i log in as a authorized user where breach is showing true. i get false still (which is right) but i shouldn't get false when it is empty.

Comment: Side note: unlike SQL, PHP actually has a [boolean type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way around this. Each page does not need two validations of breach and log in. Once they log in on the log in page it then pushed the variables to session. So if they are not logged in the session isn't set so therefore breach isn't true. If they are logged in breach is true. SO by removing the logged in validation and just using the breach one it worked first time.